# Package com.getcapacitor.community.bglocation does not exist

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app, capacitor, quasar-framework, capacitor-plugin

I just installed the capacitor-background-geolocation plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-background-geolocation)
and when I import the package in my main activity file, it displays an error "Package com.getcapacitor.community.bglocation does not exist"

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXVHx.png)

I need to the app to share the user's position in background for an hour ( updates position each 5 minute s)
any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

did you add the proper dependency to the `build.gradle` file?
sometimes it is necessary to `invalidate caches and  restart the IDE` either...